# react native login unique identifier

Tags: android, ios, react-native, imei

I have an app with no login on react native.

So what are the possibilities that I can use for uniquely identifying the user on both ios & android. Such that if user clear the cache or reinstall the app so I can identify which device is reinstalling.

Using IMEI is a good option or not. Then what about ios. And do firebase provide anything for this scenario?